# Threads getting stuck in ssh connection (perl)

Tags: multithreading, perl, ssh

I'm working on a scrip which idea is to create threads and simultaneously go throughout a list of machines and check for things. It appears that when a thread goes into it's separate terminal using "ssh ......" it gets stuck and I can't kill it. They also have a timer which doesn't seem to be working.

Here is the code:

```
sub call_cmd{
    my $host = shift;
    my $cmd = shift;
    my $command = $cmd;
    my $message;

    open( DIR, "$cmd|" ) || die "No cmd: $cmd $!";
    while(<DIR>){
        $message.=$_;
        print "\n $host $message \n";
    }
    close DIR;

    print "I'm here";
}

sub ssh_con($$){

my $host = $_[0]; 
my $cmd = "ssh $host -l $_[1]";
call_cmd($host,$cmd);

}
```

I get the output message which the ssh returns, but I never get to the next print.

This is the code for creating the threads.

```
foreach(@machines){
    my $_ = threads->create(thread_creation,$_);
    $SIG{ALRM} = sub { $_->kill('ALRM') };
    push(@threads,$_);
}

sub thread_creation(){
    my $host =  $_;

    eval{
        $SIG{ALRM} = sub { die; };
        alarm(5);
        ssh_con($host,"pblue");
        alarm(0);
    }
}
```

Output :

```
 home/pblue> perl tsh.pl

 ssh XXXXX -l pblue

 ssh XXXXX -l pblue

  XXXXX Last login: Mon Sep 30 10:39:01 2013 from ldm052.wdf.sap.corp


  XXXXX Last login: Mon Sep 30 10:39:01 2013 from ldm052.wdf.sap.corp
```

Comment: This code has a high degree of WTF. You are naming a handle on a process `DIR`, and close if after having read the 1st line. You don't show us where `call_cmd` is called. You overwrite all your `ALRM` handlers. `alarm` works on a per-process level, and yet you use threads – a recipy for heisenbugs and mayhem. Did you `use strict; use warnings`? And could you show the exact output you are getting? I have no idea what to make of your code.

Comment: I tried closing it after reading the first line to see whether the threads will get out of the ssh connection but it didn't seem to work. I've added the call_cmd although it's basicly just forming the command to be executed.

Comment: Consider using [Net::OpenSSH::Parallel](https://metacpan.org/module/Net::OpenSSH::Parallel).

Answer (score 0):

Aside from your code being a little odd, I have encountered your issue - specifically in Perl 5.8.8 on RHEL 5.

It seems there's a race condition, where if you spawn two ssh processes within a thread simultaneously, they deadlock. The only solution I have found is a workaround whereby you declare:

```
my $ssh_lock : shared;
```

And then 'open' your ssh as a filehandle:

```
my $ssh_data:
{
    lock ( $ssh_lock );
    open ( my $ssh_data, "|-", "ssh -n $hostname $command" ); 
}
#lock out of scope, so released
while ( <$ssh_data> ) {
    #do something
}
```

However this may well be a moot point on newer versions of perl/newer operating systems. I certainly couldn't reproduce it particularly reliably though, and it went away entirely when I started using `fork()` instead.

That said - your code is doing some rather strange things. Not least that the command you are running is:

```
ssh $host -l pblue
```

Which is a valid command, but it'll start ssh interactively - but because you're multithreading, that'll do very strange things with standard in and stdout.

You should also be very careful with `signal`s with multithreading - it doesn't work too well, because of the nature of the inter-process communication. Setting an ALARM signal

For a similar sort of thing - e.g. running commands via ssh - I've had a degree of success with an approach like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

use threads;
use threads::shared;
use Thread::Queue;

my @servers_to_check = qw ( hostname1 hostname2 hostname3 hostname4 );

my $num_threads = 10;

my $task_q = Thread::Queue->new;
my $ssh_lock : shared;

sub worker_thread {
    my ($command_to_run) = @_;
    while ( my $server = $task_q->dequeue ) {
        my $ssh_results;
        {
            lock($ssh_lock);
            my $pid = open( $ssh_results, "-|",
                "ssh -n $server $command_to_run" );
        }
        while (<$ssh_results>) {
            print;
        }
        close($ssh_results);
    }
}

for ( 1 .. $num_threads ) {
    threads->create( \&worker_thread, "df -k" );
}

$task_q->enqueue(@servers_to_check);
$task_q->end;

foreach my $thr ( threads->list ) {
    $thr->join();
}
```

Comment: Yea this works as a work around and everything is set up in simular manner. I'm not able to use newer versions of perl since the machines are build server. The idea was to start up in interactive and continue with commands based on the evaluated output anyway it currently executes a command then evaluates and fires a new ssh. Thanks anyway :)

Comment: If you're trying to do that, you'll need `IPC::Open2` to allow you to connect both `STDIN` and `STDOUT`.